# CiviVolunteer Interest form actions

Tags: profile, activities, civivolunteer

I've installed CiviVolunteer and have a public facing interest form at http://example.org/civicrm/volunteer/join

But all this seems to do is create a contact. It doesn't put the contact anywhere that we can easily find them to tell them of volunteer opportunities. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It adds them to CiviCRM and then you can search for them. You likely need to add a group or tag (I like a group, as I use it for mailing lists) to the settings for the profile that you are using. Then anytime someone fills out that form, they are added to your Volunteer group. Then inside CiviCRM you can easily run a search to pull the entire list of everyone who has signed up on that form.

And by using a group, you can then send them emails with volunteer opportunities - just make sure you select that it's for mailings when you create the group.

Comment: The profile used by this url is created by civivolunteer and does not let me add groups on submit...

Comment: Does the profile not show on the listing of profiles in the admin area? According to this page, it's just a profile at its core: https://docs.civicrm.org/volunteer/en/latest/interest-form/

Comment: Thats right. It uses a reserved profile created by civi volunteer called Notify Me of Volunteer Opportunities. You cannot edit settings for reserved profies, so I cannot make it add contacts to any groups.

I can of course create my own profile to collect this data and add contacts to a custom group but it kinda defeats the object of Civi Volunteer providing this facility....